# GUI library on Atmel embedded platform (Artila M-9G45A)

Tags: java, linux, qt, embedded

What is the best and fast way to develop a GUI to an embedded linux platform, which has a not so big community of developers? For example, Artila M-9G45A
Which library can I use for a fast GUI prototyping?

Comment: Didn't you get any examples along with that device?

Comment: No. Unfortunately nothing. It would be great is someone has already worked on it.